# How to calculate a percentage from BigInt?

Tags: javascript, bigint

In my code, I have an enemy object who has a `current_hp` and `max_hp`. Both are of type `BigInt`. I am looking to convert that into a percentage but in `range(0, 100)`. How can I do it effectively?

`BigInt` division rounds to integer, so I can't use fractions and do `hp/max_hp`.

Comment: What about BigDecimal?

Comment: Do you really need to support enemies with more than 9_007_199_254_740_991 HP? If not, why not just use numbers instead of BigInts? Numbers are simpler and faster than BigInts.

Answer (score 7):

Since you need the percentage in range [0, 100], you can multiply **current_hp** by **100n**:

```
current_hp_percentage = current_hp * 100n / max_hp
```

If you need a more accurate percentage (ie: including **K** decimals), you can further multiply the multiplier by 10<sup>**K**</sup>. For example, in order to print 2 decimals, you can use the following code:

```
current_hp_percentage = parseInt(current_hp * 10000n / max_hp) / 100
```

Comment: Just don't use `parseInt(...)` for BigInt-to-Number conversions, please. Use `Number(...)`, avoid the conversion to string and back.